# How do I add the same method to all objects in the model generated by ASP.NET for the same purpose?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model

This question is related to another question I asked on this site but I think I have to post a new question to get an answer. That question is: [How do I get the values of the properties of a model object in ASP.NET MVC when passed in as an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59400985/how-do-i-get-the-values-of-the-properties-of-a-model-object-in-asp-net-mvc-when)

I would like to add a method to each of the model classes that were generated by MVC for the database tables. I want to be able to write information to a log about any object from the model by just calling some method on each object. It could be .LogInfo and would return a string. Currently I am using JSON serialization in my logging method and I pass in whatever object I want to log about. I have to knock out certain fields with the [JsonIgnore] attribute to prevent sensitive information being written to the  log. It would be better to have to affirmatively add each field I want to log to some method.

I feel like I should be extending a class that contains an abstract .LogInfo method that each class from my model should extend. But I don't think I can do that, even with partial classes.

Is there some way this can be done with some facility I don't know about? If I add the .LogInfo method to each model class, then it would be wiped out if I have to regenerate the model. Maybe this is acceptable, but I am wondering if there is a more proper way.

This is how I cam declaring my LogEvent method, so I can pass in any object from the model:

```
public void LogEvent(string userName, int? userID, int? townID, string httpVerb, string description, bool isError, Object obj)
{
    JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    settings.MaxDepth = 1;
    settings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
    string bigText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, settings);
    LogEvent(userName, userID, townID, httpVerb, description, isError, bigText);
}
```

because I have another overloaded method that takes the last parameter as a string and writes it to the log.

but I would rather be doing this:

```
public void LogEvent(string userName, int? userID, int? townID, string httpVerb, string description, bool isError, Object obj)
{
    LogEvent(userName, userID, townID, httpVerb, description, isError, obj.LogInfo());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Each class generated by EF is actually a partial class.

```cs
public partial class SomeObject
```

This means you can add to them in another file. Create another file of your own, and add your method there:

```cs
public partial class SomeObject
{
    public string LogInfo(object objToLog)
    {
        // do log stuff here
    }
}
```

This way, your new method will not be overwritten if you regenerate the model.

Answer (score 1):

First, define a base class that gets the LogInfo for you.

```
class EntityBase
{
    public string LogInfo()
    {
        return JsonConvert.Serialize(this);  //Just an example
    }
}
```

Now define partial classes for your models. These partial classes will be merged with the ones that EF generates. When you define them, add the base class inheritance; this will propogate to the EF classes when you compile, even though the inheritance is only declared in one place (see [If a partial class inherits from a class then all other partials classes should also inherit the base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21794381/if-a-partial-class-inherits-from-a-class-then-all-other-partial-classes-with-the)).

```
partial class MyEntity : EntityBase
{
    //You don't actually have to put anything here unless you want to override LogInfo
}
```

Now change your logging method and specify the base class instead of object:

```
public void LogEvent(string userName, int? userID, int? townID, string httpVerb, string description, bool isError, EntityBase obj)
{
    LogEvent(userName, userID, townID, httpVerb, description, isError, obj.LogInfo());
}
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much! What I didn't know is this: If a partial class inherits from a class then all other partial classes should also inherit the base class.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension method:

```
public static class LogExtensions
{
    public static void LogInfo(this YourModelType model)
    {
        //do your logging
    }
}
```

that can be used like that:

```
var model = new YourModelType();
model.LogInfo();
```